# Spring Transaction Annotations - get active transaction

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

In my Spring application I have service-layer methods marked as `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)` and am using `<tx:annotation-driven />`. Normally the default behavior of automatically committing the transaction when the method completes works like a charm. But in the particular case, I need to commit shortly before the end of the method - yes, even if the parts that come after that point throw an exception.

Is there a way inside such a method to get access to the current transaction? I tried this:

```
TransactionDefinition td = new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_MANDATORY); // make sure we're talking about the same transaction already provided by the annotation
TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(td);

// perform various JDBC operations

transactionManager.commit(status);
methodThatNeedsToBeCalledAfterCommit();
```

But looking through my logs, I only see "AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(752) | Initiating transaction commit" occurring once, and from the timestamps this appears to be *after* `methodThatNeedsToBeCalledAfterCommit()`, which would be the normal behavior for `@Transactional` methods.

Is there a way to actually force a commit inside such a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Moreover, Spring  will try to recommit at the end of your method.
So 2 commits : bad.

You should rethink the organization of your methods.
Maybe divide the existing one in 2 methods : one with @Trnasactional, the other with your remaining lines.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't necessarily mind the recommit at the end. But from a design standpoint, this really does belong in a single method.

Comment: So do not use the annotation for this method and use the manual way of using transations. You will have complete control over your transaction.

Comment: Well, my code above is pretty much doing the manual thing anyway right? So I'm ok with that. But I'd like to be able to use the same transaction I'm already using. In particular this is because this method is also called from a JUnit test that has `@Rollback` set.

Comment: But if you manually commit in the code, the @Rollback in the unit test won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the default transaction propagation is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, and so will commit only when the entire transaction is completed - which is the outer method for you. You can try with PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW:

`td.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);`

Another alternative would be to use [TransactionTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this call this method from the program where you want to apply transaction.

```
     DefaultTransactionDefinition transdefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
         PlatformTransactionManager manager =new  PlatformTransactionManager(); 
         TransactionStatus status=null;




public void beginTransaction()
    {

        transdefinition.setPropagationBehavior(0); 


         status = manager.getTransaction(transdefinition);
    }

public void commitTransaction()
    {
if(status.isCompleted()){
manager.commit(status);
    }
}

 public void rollbackTransaction()
    {
if(!status.isCompleted()){
       manager.rollback(status);  
    }
}
```